# Was the Nazi Hakenkreuz logo based on the Indic swastika?

Tags: history, india, adolf-hitler, nazi-germany, hinduism

"[Swastika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swastika)" is sanskrit word for an ancient geometrical symbol, broadly used in Indic cultures. Amongst countries that were involved with World War II, it is associated with the Nazi flag, designed by Adolf Hitler, which used a stylised swastika referred to as "Hakenkreuz" (hooked cross).

[Swarajya Magazine](https://swarajyamag.com/ideas/swastika-is-hindu-and-the-hooked-cross-is-nazi-the-rest-is-conspiracy), a popular Indian right-wing outlet, claims that Hitler's use of the symbol had nothing to do with the Indic swastika, and was instead entirely based on a Christian Cross variant seen by Hitler at an [Austrian monastery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambach_Abbey).

> What was Hitler’s party symbol and where did he find it?
>
> It is a common misconception that Hitler used the Swastika symbol. But
>   Hitler himself never used the word "Swastika" to refer to his symbol.
>   He called it “Hooked Cross”(“Haken Kreuz”).
>
> Hitler first saw the Hooked Cross symbol in a Christian monastery
>   (Lambach Abbey) which he attended as a boy. He later adopted it as
>   an emblem for his party. There is no evidence that he ever heard of
>   the word “Swastika”. Hooked Cross had been a sacred symbol of
>   Christianity since its inception in ancient days and it is very
>   natural to find Hooked Cross symbol in old churches and chapels.

Did Hitler ever claim that the Hakenkreuz used in the Nazi flag was derived from a Christian abbey? Or from an Indic use of a swastika?

Comment: What is the actual claim here? It is a simple geometric design. You seem to distinguish Hakenkreuz & swastika as *'words'* and in meaning or tradition. As such the nazis preferred to use a German word for the exact same symbol, which is found in native American and Japanese culture as well. But being nazi means one believes this to be an 'Aryan symbol', deeply Germanic. Thus the question here constructs a claim that is nonsensical?: 'Did some nazis say: let's take an 'Asian symbol' to represent our Germanic movement'? [The Lambach monastery legend angle might be answered well here tho…]

Comment: @LangLangC Swastika = the archaeological symbol that racial theorists of the time associated with the Aryan expansion (not necessarily Indian, but definitively not associated with Chrstianity). Hakenkreuz = a Christian symbol. I'm asking if the Nazis explicitly associated their emblem with the former.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) Let's see if I have this right. There is an emblem widely used in the Hindu community, with a sanskrit name: a swastika. Coincidentally, there is a similar looking emblem that was used in some sort of Christian monastery, with a German name: Hakenkreuz. It is widely believed that the Nazis adopted a stylised Hakenkreuz as a symbol because of its Christian theological roots, but English speakers widely refer to it as a swastika.

Comment: You, however, conjecture that maybe the Germans were actually inspired by the Hindu symbol, and want to see if we can prove that conjecture?

Comment: @Oddthinking No: it is widely-believed that the Hakenkreuz was inspired both from the Christian symbol and the archaeological (Hindu or otherwise) symbol; the linked article conjectures that the symbol was inspired by *only* the Christian symbol. I don't believe anything. I'm asking if there is evidence refuting the claim in the article, i.e. confirming the widely-held belief.

Comment: @DisplayNamecanonlycontain: Thanks. I have edited for clarity.

Comment: Hitler is reputed to have hated Christianity, so if he chose it for its Christian associations then it must have been out of disrepect. It seems unlikely to me that there is a single black & white answer as to why he chose it, but it was already in use in Europe as an emblem before the Nazi party adopted it. It seems more likely that there were several angles and considered all together, Hitler thought "yes: that does it for me." My guess is that the magazine is simply trying to distance Hinduism – it wasn't **our** swastika.

Comment: Revision 4 is great and a common claim. I say we stick with it.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Whatever [Hitler's religious views](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_views_of_Adolf_Hitler) he didn't seem reticent about using Christian symbolism.

Comment: Note that there are other ways the Nazis could have "found" the swastika, aside from India or that monastery. They could have looked at the [Finnish Air Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finnish_Air_Force#History) for example, which used a blue swastika as its emblem since 1918...

Answer (score 13):

## tl;dr:

The words "Hakenkreuz" and "swastika" describe one and the same symbol, one time in Sanskrit and English, one time in German. Some believe that this *'is'* an ancient Germanic symbol, some that it *'is'* an ancient Indic. Both these schools argue with archaeology and unbroken tradition, Both claim that this is inherited from a not merely spreading but 'conquering' Indo-European (Indo-Germanic, abbreviated: *IE*) conglomerate of 'ancestors', in this case until the 1940 popularly often called 'Aryans'. This shared similarity falls flat for the criterion of 'original invention', as there is ample 'prior art' thousands of years older than any proponent of these claims can account for and apparent 'independent invention' of older, and of non-Indo-European cultures for this simplistic symbol to be found virtually everywhere.

European nationalists and Hindu nationalists are therefore both wrong to at least come together in the claim "we (our ancestors) invented this", *even if* anyone should assert any unbroken tradition and continuity of cultures, which is also wrong in the first place.

The waning but never extinguished popularity of the hooked cross in Europe was over time largely re-interpreted as to be read as a variant of a Christian cross. Only through the reception of Indian and other 'Eastern' 'mysticisms'/religious ideas and linguistic as well as ethno-cultural studies in the 19th century, some Europeans thought this 'Indian reading' – and thus 'Aryan' – of the symbol would have preserved the 'original', or pre-Christian, reading of the ancient symbol.

The eventual Nazi-use of the symbol is therefore formed in reaction to the then 'newly found' Indian tradition and thus inseparable from the Indian variant reading. This is directly traceable through European mystics, 'Aryan' nationalists writing and usage. This political extremist right-wing reading of ultra-pan-Germanists and forgers of history became the dominating line of interpretation for this symbol in 1935, when it was made sole national flag of Germany. As the Hitler movement started in 1920 they enshrined with references to 'Eastern' meanings (and religions) this symbol as their own and through the popularity of Nazis and their iconography this is now what we look at: a universal symbol of the most simplistic design that in the West 'has' to be read as meaning much different things than in many other parts of the world. Only for the 'post'-1935 prescribed readings in the West did Hitler contribute much 'original work'.

---

The [swastika Hitler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swastika#Use_in_Nazism) inherited from his ideological [*völkisch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%B6lkisch_movement) progenitors is a universal symbol. The [swastika as it came to be used](https://encyclopedia.ushmm.org/content/en/article/history-of-the-swastika) under national-socialism is inseperable in its intellectual tradition of *reading the symbol* from the Indian variant of it. Without the Indian version and its contemporary influence in 19th century European nationalism, and a variety of other connected ideologies, the Nazi swastika is unthinkable.

That swastika was in use in the right-wing nationalist movements of the time for decades when Hitler selected it as a trademark sign for his party. Until then and some time later the symbol was still widely read as *not* specific to nazism, although this reading then came to dominate the interpretation.

The symbol is never mentioned to be of specifically 'Indian origin' by Hitler himself, neither in speeches nor in his book *Mein Kampf*. Nor is the monastery legend connected to Lambach. In his book he only makes a fleeting mention, that of all the proposals presented to him, many already including the swastika of some sorts, *he* as *Führer* selected the 'best one' and finalised it in terms of *orient*-ation, colour-scheme and proportions. It was his own, by sheer coincidence, as I am sure you will also believe…

The claim originating article therefore re-tells a lot of nazi myth and is "not true".

1. The Indian swastika and the Nazi swastika are *identical* symbols. That does not say that both *mean* the same things. Symbols are empty vessels to be filled by the expectations of the spectator. They could mean the same thing: symbol of right-wing hatred in 'White nations' or a 'Hindu nation'. Or just 'good luck'…
2. The swastika Hitler's party chose *only* came to prominence in nationalist thinking *because* it was known to be an ancient symbol of ancient India *and* the nationalist Europeans invented a tradition of 'white conquest' (or "Aryan expansion") that claimed this symbol would be proof of European identity *and* dominance, only that Europeans largely forgot it in the meantime and Indians preserved this abstract artifact in a much more widespread manner. The supposedly connecting dot being that Schliemann claimed to have excavated (in Asia!) the 'European' city of Troy where such symbols were found as well, rivaling Indian finds at the time in terms of 'boy, that's old'.
3. The claim that Hitler saw a variation of the swastika symbol in an Austrian abbey as a young boy is true.
   [image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Theoderich_hagn_vaakuna.png]
   But that he took this as inspiration for re-purposing a Christian symbol of a cross is a Nazi myth invented or [ret-conned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ret-con) only long after Hitler came to power.
   The symbolism in the monastery is clergical and thus Christian, as that [one Benedictine abbot](https://fi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theoderich_Hagn) from the 19th century chose a non-right angle variant, meant as a Christian cross, as his personal heraldic symbol. While Hitler was deeply influenced by Catholicism and used its methods and doctrines atavistically, the whole goal of his enterprise was to root it in a 'more original' way, an older way, as 'older' was better. The *pagan* pre-Christian tradition of pre-Germanic peoples of this symbol has therefore precendence. **The 'young Hitler got it from abbey' is a nazi lie.'** (cf: Grossruck)
   And not even an '*official* nazi lie'. The swastika was in use in that nationalist scene long before Hitler joined any party, he never mentioned the connection to the abbey, and surely not as in 'want a Hakenkreuz just like in my childhood abbey', and *local* nazis in Lambach (Austria!) took the opportunity to paint a short-staying Hitler getting inspired as a 'city's great son' (after [Anschluss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anschluss) in 1938!). Despite the symbols only vaguely matching, representing different things, Hitler ignoring that completely and the folk-etymology of a [*'Hagn-Kreuz'*](https://www.nachrichten.at/oberoesterreich/wels/Nazi-Tourismus-Abt-laesst-Hakenkreuz-entfernen;art67,1968630) giving rise to a *Hitler's Hakenkreuz* being ridiculously far-fetched and easily seen as completely ahistorical.

> In 1883, however, an Austrian schoolmaster, the gymnasium professor [Carl Penka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Penka), published [a monograph](https://archive.org/details/originesariacae01penkgoog/page/n8/mode/2up) that made the claim that the Indo-Europeans were indigenous to Europe and had expanded into the orient by conquest. This notion of indigeneity soon began to receive support from German academics and by the turn of the century had achieved some level of academic respectability. The early proponents of an Indo-European origin in Germany clearly fed off anthropological speculation; yet they were also obviously arguing a national question.
>
> Very soon the connection between German, Germanic and Indo-European (the latter identity still to this day usually termed *indogermanisch*, i.e. Indo-Germanic, in German) was also to become a mainstay of *völkisch* thought too.
>
> With the siting of the aryan homeland in the German north, the Aryan identity received new importance. [Chamberlain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Houston_Stewart_Chamberlain), after all, had bound classical antiquity and ancient Germany together as chapters in an [Aryan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryan#Nazism_and_white_supremacy) antiquity. He had used the term Aryan only in its anthropological sense (which is more clearly described as Nordic or Caucasian), but as the realization of the implications of Indo-European linguistics entered anthropological and archeological discourse in the later decades of the nineteenth century, the anthropological identity Aryan had become fused with the linguistic one. Aryan only properly designates the Indo-European peoples of India and Iran (and indeed the latter place-name derives from ‘aryan’). Yet when [Schliemann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_Schliemann) discovered symbols identical to Hindu swastikas among his much-publicized discoveries at Troy, swastikas became the symbols of an occidental Aryan identity. The Greeks of Homer, no longer the mythical figures they had once seemed, now represented the oldest of occidental Indo-European cultures, one even as old as ancient India and Persia. As an occidental hallmark of Aryan culture, Schliemann’s swastika soon also came to penetrate *völkisch* literature: the connection between Aryan (Indo-Germanic) and Teuton (Germanic) had achieved a physical, concrete and easily recognizable symbol. [Goblet d’Alviella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eug%C3%A8ne_Goblet_d%27Alviella)’s study was also employed to show that although the swastika was widely known throughout the world’s cultures, the earliest examples of the symbol were attested only in central Europe. D’Alviella’s diagrammatic depiction of the distribution of swastikas in Europe and Asia became a mainstay of both academic and *völkisch* interpretations of the origin and nature of the swastika. The swastika became the symbol par excellence of the Aryan, or in anthropological terms, the white race.
>
> By the 1920s swastika studies had developed a number of theories about the swastika and what were thought to be related prehistorical symbols: the circle, the circle-cross and the cross itself (which according to [Montelius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscar_Montelius) had been adopted by the church from prehistoric practice). The connection of the sun with these symbols also led to the notion of primitive aryan sun worship, a cult which in description was clearly monotheistic.
> <sub>— Bernard Mees: ["The science of the swastika"](http://ceupress.com/book/science-swastika), Central European University Press: Budapest, New York, 2008. 'The Origins of Ideographic Studies', p57. *(Links added for convenience, LLC)*</sub>

This 19th century academic opinion which was 'scientific' is now quite outdated.

The oldest *civilisation* using the swastika/Hakenkreuz in Europe wqs the pre- and non-Indo-European, old-European Danube or [Vinça-culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vin%C4%8Da_symbols) (5700 BC). The [proto Indo-European homeland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_homeland) may from 4000 BC be the 'point of origin' for Indo-Europeans, but while the absolute dating for that may be a bit unclear, it is not unclear that the early Indo-Europeans did not use anything archaeology could dig up that 'knows' this symbol. They 'learned it' from contact with that older civilisation.

Similar patterns can be seen for Finno-uralic peoples, Siberian, Chinese and [Harappan culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indus_Valley_Civilisation). All used the symbol before Indo-Europeans 'made contact' with them, and then the latter adopted the symbol. As seen by [Andronovo people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andronovo_culture) (IE), Helladic migrants to Greece or Aryans in India.
<sub>(— Harald Haarmann: "Auf den Spuren der Indoeuropäer: Von den neolithischen Steppennomaden bis zu den frühen Hochkulturen", CH Beck: München, 2016. [gBooks](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=peWhCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT2))</sub>

In Hitler's *Mein Kampf* we get a glimpse of how this committee work for choosing a brand played out:

> Die Frage der neuen Flagge, d.h. ihr Aussehen, beschäftigte uns damals sehr stark. Es kamen von allen Seiten Vorschläge, die allerdings meist besser gemeint als gut gelungen waren.
> […]
> Dennoch mußte ich die zahllosen Entwürfe, die damals aus den Kreisen der jungen Bewegung einliefen, und die meistens das Hakenkreuz in die alte Fahne hineingezeichnet hatten, ausnahmslos ablehnen. Ich selbst – als Führer – wollte nicht sofort mit meinem eigenen Entwurf an die Öffentlichkeit treten, da es ja möglich war, daß ein anderer einen ebenso guten oder vielleicht auch besseren bringen würde. Tatsächlich hat ein Zahnarzt aus Starnberg auch einen gar nicht schlechten Entwurf geliefert, der übrigens dem meinen ziemlich nahekam, nur den einen Fehler hatte, daß das Hakenkreuz mit gebogenen Haken in eine weiße Scheibe hineinkomponiert war.
> Ich selbst hatte unterdes nach unzähligen Versuchen eine endgültige Form niedergelegt; eine Fahne aus rotem Grundtuch mit einer weißen Scheibe und in deren Mitte ein schwarzes Hakenkreuz. Nach langen Versuchen fand ich auch ein bestimmtes Verhältnis zwischen der Größe der Fahne und der Größe der weißen Scheibe sowie der Form und Stärke des Hakenkreuzes.
> Und dabei ist es dann geblieben.
> <sub>— (AH: "MK", 1925, p555–556. [translation here](https://www.fahnenversand.de/fotw/flags/de%7Dns_or.html))</sub>

Coincidentally, in this passage AH explicitly rejects a shape more closely resembling the monastery symbol than what we later saw on nazi flags.…

In this design finding stage for the brand we are looking at the years 1919-20. With the swastika being a well established *völkisch* and anti-semitic symbol we also find AH still struggling to choose 'the correct' version, in contrast to his *fait accompli* characterisation in *Mein Kampf*:

> [image: https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Datei:AdolfHitler_Hakenkreuz1920.jpg&filetimestamp=20090201165511&]
> <sub>Before May 1920: "The sacred signs of the Germans(Teutons). One of these signs should be resurrected again by us."
>
> — [Rüdiger Sünner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%BCdiger_S%C3%BCnner): ["Schwarze Sonne. Entfesselung und Mißbrauch der Mythen in Nationalsozialismus und rechter Esoterik"](https://books.google.com/books/about/Schwarze_Sonne.html?id=Q2F5AAAAMAAJ), Herder: Freiburg, Basel, Wien, 1999. (P177. Original in possession of the Bavarian Ministry of Finances.)</sub>

The direct connection between swastika using predecessor organisations in Germany and the NSDAP of Hitler — excluding the antecendent armed militants like *Freikorps* (example: [Marienbrigade Erhardt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marinebrigade_Ehrhardt)) — was Friedrich Krohn, the infamous "[dentist](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322273909_Der_Zahnarzt_aus_Mein_Kampf_-_Die_biografischen_Selbstdeutungen_des_Starnberger_Dentisten_Friedrich_Krohn_1897-1967)" from *Mein Kampf*:

> Although the [DAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Workers%27_Party) and the [Thule Society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thule_Society) diverged in their views on ideology and action, there was a direct line of symbological succession between the two groups in the form of the swastika. Friedrich Krohn, a Thulean and a member of the *[Germanenorden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanenorden)* since 1913, had earned the reputation of a DAP expert as a result of his collection of some 2,500 books on *völkisch* subjects for the use of party members. In May 1919 Krohn wrote a memorandum with the title *'Ist das Hakenkreuz als Symbol nationalsozialistischer Partei geeignet?'* ['Is the swastika suitable as the symbol of the National Socialist Partv?'] in which he proposed the left-handed swastika (i.e.clockwise in common with those of the theosophists and the Germanenorden) as the symbol of the DAP. He evidently preferred the sign in this direction **on account of its Buddhistical interpretation as a talisman of fortune and health,** whereas its right-handed (i.e. anti-clockwise) counterpart betokened decline and death. (However, since most Listian swastikas and the device of the Thule Society had been right-handed, it is clear that there was no standard usage regarding the direction of the swastika in the *völkisch* tradition). Hitler actually favoured a right-handed, straight-armed swastika and prevailed upon Krohn in DAP committee discussions to revise his design. Krohn was responsible for the colour scheme of a black swastika in a white circle on a red background. At the foundation meeting of the local Starnberg group of the NSDAP on 20 May 1920, this swastika, originally proposed by Krohn and modified by Hitler, made its first public appearance as the flag of the new movement. It is therefore possible to trace the origin of the Nazi symbol back through the emblems of the Germanenorden and ultimately to [Guido von List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_von_List).
> <sub>— Nicholas Goodrick-Clarke: ["The Occult Roots of Nazism: Secret Aryan Cults and Their Influence on Nazi Ideology"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Occult_Roots_of_Nazism), I B Tauris: Londion, New York, p151, 2004.</sub>

— Malcolm Quinn: ["The Swastika: Constructing the Symbol"](https://collections.ushmm.org/search/catalog/bib5542), Material Cultures, Routledge: London, New York, 1994.

— Thomas Wilson: "The Swastika. the Earliest Known Symbol and its Migrations; With Observations on the Migration of Certain Industries in Prehistoric Times", U.S. National museum, 1896. (various [version on archive.org](https://archive.org/details/32882006810041))

— Johann Grossruck: ["Benediktinerstift  Lambach im Dritten Reich 1938 –1945. Ein Kloster im Fokus von Hitlermythos und Hakenkreuzlegende"](http://www.wagnerverlag.at/content/?product=benediktinerstift-lambach-im-dritten-reich-1938-1945), Wagner Verlag: Linz, 2011. (Esp p 151–174; [review](http://www.wagnerverlag.at/content/?product=benediktinerstift-lambach-im-dritten-reich-1938-1945))

How 'the dentist' Krohn tried to seel the idea in his text reads:

> Personally I may add in all modesty that I found the swastika (sun wheel) *[(in German original: "Hakenkreuz", LLC)]* in 1912 also on an old coat of arms of our family and therefore I am also personally very attached to this sign. Therefore I would like to ask especially my party friends of the DSP or the DAP and the Wälsungenorden / Thulegesellschaft to choose this victory sign as a symbol of ***our occidental defence*** and struggle of renewal, as our brave fighters ***against the Asian red hordes*** in the east in the *Freikorps* partly did use already. Sieg  und Heil!
> <sub>— own translation, quoted from: Sibylle Friedrike Hellerer: "Die NSDAP im Landkreis Starnberg. Von den Anhängen bis zur Konsolidierung der Macht (1919-1938)", Dissertation, Ludwig-Maximilians-Universität München, 2014. ([PDF](https://edoc.ub.uni-muenchen.de/21189/7/Hellerer_Sibylle_Friedrike.pdf))</sub>

Net ressources:
— Peter Diem: ["Die Entwicklung des Hakenkreuzes zum todbringenden Symbol des Nationalsozialismus"](https://austria-forum.org/af/Wissenssammlungen/Symbole/Hakenkreuz), [mirror](http://peter-diem.at/Buchtexte/hakenkreuz.htm)
— [Heraldik-Wiki: Swastika](https://www.heraldik-wiki.de/wiki/Swastika)

The frame of this question is quite odd. A basic geometric shape when interpreted as a symbol of magical qualities that is found throughout all of history and across the globe does not carry any inherent meaning. This 'meaning' is solely attached to it by the viewer and thus one probably shouldn't say that this *is* an 'Indian symbol', or a 'nazi symbol'. It is much better fitting to describe this shape as 'is *used* by' Hindus or Nazis, as just two examples. This doesn't change the fact that in contemporary Western culture the association between swastika and nazism is almost congruent now, if not a relationship of identity. But as such, this [invented tradition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invented_tradition) came late:

> In 1891, when Michael Zmigrodski defined the swastika as the armorial shield of the Aryan race, his heraldic metaphor was apposite in several senses: the Aryan swastika was both the precursor heralding an absent or delayed referent meaning, and also its defensive shield. It was also heraldic insofar as the ‘tradition of the symbol’ and the repetition of the sign was a mimesis of racial lineage and pedigree. In this ‘heraldic’ form, the swastika itself does not ‘mean’, it produces meaning by announcing it on the one hand and obscuring it on the other.
> <sub>(— Quinn)</sub>

It is bit of a cat and mouse game here: 19th century Europeans saw the Indic swastika and admired the oldness of that culture and liked this recognisable symbol. Then they found the same symbol and close relatives of it in their archaeological excavations 'closer to home' and sometimes even older than from India. They 're-discovered' the symbol as 'our own', despite it never fading completely from decorations or [heraldry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fylfot). Instead of assuming a parallel development of a simplistic structure, they *wanted* a single point of origin, an 'unbroken tradition' and concluded 'conquest' and domination from that. No matter how implausible and of course disregarding any evidence to the contrary.

In Nazi/European ideology, 'the Indic swastika is inherited from Aryan ancestors', not the other way around. Whether Hindus, stone-age people or Germanic peoples also used it is irrelevant, we see it in constant [cultural appropriation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_appropriation)…

That means in European heraldry, a swastika is not so rarae as many may believe now:

> will not rehearse either the purported ancient origins of the swastika or the manifold contexts in which swastika-like devices are found. Like others who have written on the subject, I find, in any case, that such an approach fails comprehensively to mitigate the instinctive reaction the swastika now inspires in the West. On the contrary, the nineteenth-century antiquarian practice of spotting swastikas and building connections played a major part in the construction of what the swastika was to become.
> <sub>— Clive Cheesman: "The Heralds’ Swastika", in: Fiona Robertson and Peter N. Lindfield (Eds): "The Display of Heraldry.  The Heraldic Imagination in Arts and Culture", The Coat Of Arms Supplementary Volume No 1, The Heraldry Society: London, 2019.</sub>

By the time Hitler was born in 1889 and then afterwards, he could have seen that symbol in lots of places, like the aforementioned abbey. But there it was a Christian symbol. It was not so much Christian in Rudyard [Kipling's books](https://archive.org/details/cu31924013493105), on [beer bottles from Carlsberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_use_of_the_swastika_in_the_early_20th_century). And it was firmly established then to this Germanic/Aryan reading-thing through many writings, and respected artworks:

[image]
<sub>— Mårten Eskil Winge: "Thor's Fight with the Giants" (1872) (Referenced on [Wikipedia: "Early Germanic culture"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Germanic_culture) no less. Hint: the belt.)</sub>

Therefore, the claim that "Adolf Hilter probably never heard the word swastika" is quite the bogus one. The "[Swastika](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=swastika)" and "[Hakenkreuz](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Swastika)" are perfect synonyms, and one is the [usual](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Swastika) German translation for the other (the ['proper' German word being in dictionaries from at  least the 18th century](https://lexika.digitale-sammlungen.de/adelung/lemma/bsb00009132_3_0_319)). Just that there are certain preferences around any particular usage:

> This caveat was issued in 1880 by the philologist Max Müller in a letter to the archaeologist Heinrich Schliemann, then known throughout Europe as the excavator of Troy. In his letter, Müller warned Schliemann that he should be wary of confusing the word ‘swastika’ with an archaeological ‘found image’, and that to do so would sever the links between the symbol and tradition:
>
> > I do not like the use of the word Svastika outside India. It is a word of Indian origin, and has its history and definite meaning in India. I know the temptation is great to transfer names, with which we are familiar, to similar objects which come before us in the course of our researches. But it is a temptation which the true student ought to resist, except, it may be, for the sake of illustration. The mischief arising from the promiscuous use of technical terms is very great.
> > <sub>(— Quinnn, p1)</sub>

Comment: Am I correct in reading your answer as follows? (1) the Nazis themselves claimed the abbey story as the source (2) but this is a lie, because the Swastika, inspired by archaeological finds, was already widely considered an "Aryan symbol" by pre-Nazi racialists. In which case, I don't really understand the motivation for the Nazis to come up with this lie: if, as you say, the Nazis were attracted to "older" symbols, why would they lie that their symbol is of more recent origin?

Comment: @anon Difference in timeline: the abbey story is true for 'saw that version' but a very late invention/lie (30s) for 'inspiration', and used to construct a pseudo-continuity: that the abbot himself supposedly chose an ancient Germanic symbol (superimposed on unimportant fad: Christian cross, because: 'fatum'/ in concordance with 'his race', 'providence' for the young boy fuehrer to see it there as well…). It's trying to fit into a back projection of 'our symbol was always there' and a ridiculous strawman for modern swastika-aficionados to distance themselves from nazis: "nazi = 1 symbol only".

Comment: OK I see what you're saying, but your answer still doesn't convince me: your main evidence seems to be the use of the symbol as an invented tradition by pre-Nazi "Aryan" racialists. But to claim that the Nazis were basing their symbolism off this, one would need to show that this connection was sufficiently widespread among said racialists for the Nazis to believe in the story of the Swastika being an Aryan symbol. Also, shouldn't there be at least some Nazi sources that explicitly state this connection?

Comment: +1, but I think your question could use a TL;DR at the top.  If I understand correctly, the swastika was an Indian symbol discovered in European archeological digs, nationalists took that as proof that the symbol originated in Europe and appropriated it for their purposes in the late 19th century, and the idea of Hitler coming up with the design is false because it was in use well before that?

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to know Hitler's inner motives. They were quite out there. To be more precise, the motives to use swastikas were out there for Coca-Cola, Boy Scouts and California fruit producers.  [The Man Who Brought the Swastika to Germany, and How the Nazis Stole It](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/man-who-brought-swastika-germany-and-how-nazis-stole-it-180962812/)

The motives were so out there that they disprove what your linked site wanted to prove. It wasn't a 1000 year old monastery that inspired Hitler. It was thousand year old Troy, city from Homers Illiad. It was there where Dr. Schliemann discovered stone age old swastikas. And describe them as signs of "Aryan race". But in the late 19th century *Aryan* meant the Indo-European language group.

And this is the source of motive to use the swastika. Arthur de Gobineau made a connection of made up Aryans, a race of "pure" humans and Germans. Early 20th century German nationalists groups draw from that stating that they are Aryans and therefore have right to conquer neighbours as they are merelly "reclaiming" old territory. To prove that they used the swastika symbol as a connection beetwen them and symbols found in Troy.

The problem is that there is no specific source of the symbol. It can be found in Asia, the Americas, Africa, Ireland and Korea. We cannot say "it was made in Troy and then copied in India" or vice versa. Or that the symbol was made up parallel in multiple places and has no connections beetwen them. [Project Gutenberg THE SWASTIKA by Thomas Wilson](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/40812/40812-h/40812-h.htm#Page_802)

But Nazi German use was fueled by will to prove that they are the first people in Europe and have more right than others to own land and live.

Therefore - the claim in the linked article can be easily refuted. **BUT** it don't prove the opposite. It can just prove that the boths statements are wrong. *Saying things opposite to a lie don't make them true*

Comment: I'm aware that the Nazis were obsessed with the Indo-European/Aryan expansion, and that other German academics related the archaeological Swastika to the Aryan expansion. But this does not prove that the Nazi use of the symbol was motivated by this connection. This seems like a claim that needs a primary source.

Comment: "*the claim in the linked article can be easily refuted. BUT it don't prove opposite*" This makes no sense. If the claim in the article is indisputably false, then its opposite (i.e. logical negation) must be indisputably true. That would be a "proof". In any case, this is not an answer: I'm asking for a specific reference of the Nazis claiming their symbolism to be related to what racial theorists of the time considered the Aryan Swastika.

Comment: @DisplayNamecanonlycontain Hitler made a connection between the swastika and the "victory of Aryan mankind" in [Mein Kampf](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks02/0200601.txt): "the swastika signified the mission allotted to us--the struggle for the victory of Aryan mankind and at the same time the triumph of the ideal of creative work which is in itself and always will be anti-Semitic."

Comment: @DisplayNamecanonlycontain How you expect logical negation to work in statements. I'm 6 foot tall. I say "I'm 7 feet tall", someone says "That's not true, you're 100 feet tall". By refuting the last sentence with biological reason you didn't proved the first one true. And you cannot assume that "The opposite must be true". Because what is opposite to such stament?

Comment: What are you calling the "opposite" of the article's claim when you say the "it doesn't prove opposite"?

Comment: @DisplayNamecanonlycontain "Nazi Hakenkreuz was not inspired from the Indic Swastika, but from a Christian Cross variant seen by Hitler at an Austrian monastery." So by refuting the "christian cross" statement I didn't proven that it was Indic Swastika.

Comment: Wait, how does this answer refute the "Christian cross" statement? Even proving that it was the Indic Swastika wouldn't refute the Christian cross origin, as the Nazis may have intended multiple things.

Comment: @DisplayNamecanonlycontain Do you realize when in timeline stone age Troy is located and how far, in time, it was to not only Christ and his cross but to monastery build 1000 years after his presumed death?

Comment: I fail to see how the Trojan Swastika being older has anything to do with what the Nazis were interested in.